# Problem with adding custom post type meta to header by plugin

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, post-meta, headers

I'm trying to write a plugin by which a meta code will be added to specific post type header.
I tried to use this code:

```
function msc_header() {
if ( is_singular( 'article' ) ) {
        echo '<meta name="site_title" content="'.'test test'.'">'."\n";
        }
}
add_action('wp_head','msc_header', 0);
```

But nothing happened. I got no error but no code was added. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's should be `return` rather than `echo`.

```
return '<meta name="site_title" content="'.'test test'.'">'."\n";
```